# Fix td height in ie9

Tags: html, css

I have dynamic content in a td - if the copy is too long, the cell ignores the set height and stretches. This only happens in ie9.

here is my css

```
table tr {
min-height: 58px;
height: 58px;  overflow:hidden!important;
}
table td {
border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
padding: 0 15px 0 15px;  overflow:hidden!important; height: 58px; white-space:wrap;
}
```

Not quite sure how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use td to lay out the content.  Only use tables for tabular data.  Use spans and div's and appropriate css.

This is just one of those browser things you have to accept and code for appropriately.  I'm sure it'll be fixed in ie14, but something else will break of course ;)